# CSS transform 3d cube save as image

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms, html2canvas

I create a 3d cube with css and when trying to save it  with html2canvas it not render properly. Is there any alternate method or any plugin to achieve this.

My goal is to save the rotated cube and share on social media.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#show_button").click(function () {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
      onrendered: function (canvas) {
        $("<img/>", {
          id: "image",
          src: canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
          width: '95%',
          height: '95%'
        }).appendTo($("#show_img").empty());
      }
    });
  });
});
downloadPNG = function () {
  html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
      Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body > div {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 60px auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 1100px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: -50% -50%;
  float: left;
}

.cube {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px);
  left: 15%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
}

.cube div {
  width: 298px;
  height: 188px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 110px;
  color: #fff;
  font: 3em arial;
}

.front {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(150px);
}

.left {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(150px);
}

.right {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(150px);
}

.top {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(150px);
}

.bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(150px);
}

.back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(150px);
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

label:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

input:checked + label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[value="front"]:checked ~ .container .cube {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateY(0);
}

input[value="left"]:checked ~ .container .cube {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateY(90deg);
}

input[value="right"]:checked ~ .container .cube {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateY(-90deg);
}

input[value="top"]:checked ~ .container .cube {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateX(-90deg);
}

input[value="bottom"]:checked ~ .container .cube {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateX(90deg);
}

input[value="back"]:checked ~ .container .cube {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/canvas2image/0.1/canvas2image.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/canvas2image/0.1/base64.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/canvas2image/0.1/canvas2image.js"></script>



<div>
<div style="margin-bottom:40px">
<button id="show_button">Show Image</button>
<a onclick="downloadPNG()" href="">download</a>
</div>
  <input id="front" name="transforms" type="radio" value="front">
  <label for="front">Front</label>

  <input id="left" name="transforms" type="radio" value="left">
  <label for="left">Left</label>

  <input id="right" name="transforms" type="radio" value="right">
  <label for="right">Right</label>

  <input id="top" name="transforms" type="radio" value="top">
  <label for="top">Top</label>

  <input id="bottom" name="transforms" type="radio" value="bottom">
  <label for="bottom">Bottom</label>

  <input id="back" name="transforms" type="radio" value="back">
  <label for="back">Back</label>

  <div class="container">
    <figure class="cube">
      <div class="front">Front</div>
      <div class="left">Left</div>
      <div class="right">Right</div>
      <div class="top">Top</div>
      <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
      <div class="back">Back</div>
    </figure>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="show_img"></div>
```

Genrated Image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can forget doing that with html2canvas, phantomjs or wkhtmltopdf. I haven't found anything that supports css3 transformations yet, but...

You can 1st do the 3D with imageMagic, THEN pass it to html2canvas as a new image (if you have more stuff to render together with the 3D).